# Is the curve always continuous if both $x=f(t)$, $y=g(t)$ are continuous?

Tags: calculus, continuity, curves, parametric

Initially I thought some functions like ( $x=t^2$, $y=t^4$) simply don't apply to this, but is there like a more general definition for continuity, or should we specify which function we are referring to, so $f$ and $g$ are continues but the curve isn't, and do they have direct correlation ($f/g$ and the curve ) in terms of continuity.

Comment: Thanks for your question! I'll give an answer, but I want to tailor it to your understanding. What is your definition of "continuous"?

Comment: It doesn't really make sense to talk about continuity of a curve - you always need a function involved.  You can, however, talk about continuity of the function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ that generates the curve.

Comment: @DMcMor That's an interesting point, but in this context I think "curve" just means the function $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ (and not the object independent of parametrization)

Comment: You will almost immediately answer your own question... If you provide in your question the definition of the continuity of a curve at a point. Give it a try!

Comment: Assuming that a function $f(x,y) ~: \Bbb{R^2} \to \Bbb{R}$ is involved, and that at a given point $z_0 = f(x_0, y_0),$ the functions $g(x, y_0)$ and $h(x_0, y)$ are continuous, consider that in a neighborhood of $\delta$ around $(x_0, y_0)$ you will have $\epsilon > |g(x,y_0) - z_0|, |h(x_0, y) - z_0|$.  Given that, then it is easy to prove that $2\epsilon > |f(x,y) - z_0|$, for $(x,y)$ in this neighborhood.

Comment: I understand that for implicit equations like y=f(x) , f is considered continuous at C if the limit of f as x is approaching C is f(C) , so for the equation given above , its not continuous at x=0 , because its not approaching it from the left , but its doesn't make sense because the curve is continuously drawn as t increases in its domain

Comment: @izzat5233 If you are talking about $x = t^2, y = t^4$, could you explain what you intend by " *it's not approaching* *it from the left* "?

Comment: x is approaching the point (0,0) only from the right , but the definition of continuity require it to reach from the left too

Comment: @izzat5233 No, the definition of continuity that I was taught, was that if $D$ was the domain, and $N$ was the neighborhood around $(0,0)$ then you only had to consider $(D \cap N)$.  In this sense, continuity is defined throughout the neighborhood.  As $x$ approaches from the left, there is no value of $x$ that is contained in $(D \cap N)$ that violates the constraint.

Comment: @user2661923 Yeah that was my question , so there is actually a proper definition than calc 1 definition for continuity , but does that mean the answer to my question is yes

Comment: @izzat5233 My (semi-rigorous) knowledge of Real Analysis has about $20$ years of cobwebs on it, so my opinion is largely intuition.  My intuition is that if you *combine* two continuous functions, the result is a continuous function.  However, my intuition is not foolproof here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The curve you are considering is given by the function $C$ whose domain is $\mathbb{R}$ and whose codomain is $\mathbb{R}^2$ (we write this as $C : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$). It is explicitly given by:
$$
C(t) = (t^2, t^4)
$$
You can also write this as $C(t) = (x(t), y(t))$ or $C(t) = (f(t), g(t))$, where $x(t) = f(t) = t^2$ and $y(t) = g(t) = t^4$.

What it means for this function $C$ to be continuous at a point $a$, as you pointed out, is that it satisfies the condition:
$$
\lim \limits_{t \rightarrow a} C(t) = C(a).
$$
Using the more technical definition of limits, you can show that this is equivalent to each of the components being continuous. Specifically, if we say that $C(t) = (f(t), g(t))$, then:
$$
\lim \limits_{t \rightarrow a} C(t) = C(a)
\qquad
\text{is equivalent to}
\qquad
\lim \limits_{t \rightarrow a} f(t) = f(a)
\text{ and }
\lim \limits_{t \rightarrow a} g(t) = g(a).
$$
So, the answer to your question is: a curve is continuous if and only if its components are all continuous.

Comment: @izzat5233 I noticed in the comments that you had some confusion regarding $x$ approaching $0$, as opposed to $t$ approaching $0$. I didn't address that in my answer, but is that cleared up for you? Or is it still bothering you?

Comment: I think i got it , we apply the definition to C(t) itself ( as t approaches ) , not to y as x approaches or x as y approaches , now it makes sense . and if we eliminate the parameter we get half the parabola y = x^2 and only then y wouldn't be continuous

Comment: @izzat5233 The first part is exactly right. I would just add a nuance to your last sentence: you do indeed get half of the parabola $y=x^2$, but the question of continuity is a bit more nuanced. Specifically, it depends on what you consider to be the domain of definition of the function. You could look into this more, but I wouldn't worry about it for this context.